# Tools for automatic storage device partitioning (embedded linux)

Tags: linux, storage, embedded-linux

I have a board with an on-board 64GB EMMC. The EMMC doesn't host rootfs and is not a boot device. I want to have the EMMC partitioned, file systems created and mounted automatically.

So far I feel like I have to create some sort of script from scratch to test if partition table is present, partitions formatted and do the job if something is wrong. And then put this script under `systemd` control to be run at some early boot stage.

Setting up storage on the very first run feels like a routine task for an  embedded linux system, therefor I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel.

Is there some sort of toolset or best practices to do that automatic storage setup?

Comment: automatic toolset? not sure. To write a script you can either use `fdisk` or `parted`. fdisk and parted are used for partitioning eMMC. You might already be aware about that.

Comment: @AnkurTank Yes, I know the basic tools, it's all about the proper way to apply them to this (seemingly) trivial task.